# How am I handling lifetimes incorrectly?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am new to rust and wanted to create a simple application that looked at stock analytics to learn. Everything was going fine until I attempted to incorporate a cache into the application. I tried many different state management approaches but found that people recommended passing state from parent to child, so that is what I attempted. So now, many functions require the mutable reference to the Cache struct declared in the main function.

At first I was doing fine just tweaking function signatures until the compiler stopped complaining; however, one function incorporates a loop, and inside the loop the cache is passed to a method. This caused the issue where multiple mutable borrows were taking place inside the iteration.

Here is the error[E0499]:

```
cannot borrow `*cache` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\screener.rs:34:54
   |
34 |                 stocks.push(Stock::new(stock.symbol, cache).await);
   |                             -------------------------^^^^^-
   |                             |                        |
   |                             |                        `*cache` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                             argument requires that `*cache` is borrowed for `'static'
```

The method where the error exist:

```
async fn symbols_to_stocks(symbols: Vec<AvailableTraded>, cache: &'static mut Cache) -> Vec<&'static mut Stock> {
    let mut stocks = vec![];

    for stock in symbols {
        if stock.type_ == "stock" && (stock.exchange_short_name == "NYSE"
            || stock.exchange_short_name == "NASDAQ")
        {
            stocks.push(Stock::new(stock.symbol, cache).await);
        }
    }

    stocks
}
```

This is the new method which I am calling inside the loop:

```
     pub async fn new(ticker: String, cache: &'static mut Cache) -> &'static mut Self {

    let index = cache.stock_index_in_cache(ticker.clone());

    if index >= 0 {
        return &mut cache.stocks[index as usize];
    }

    let stock_to_be = Self {
        ticker,
        statements: Statements::new(),
        metrics: Metrics::new(),
    };

    return cache.add_stock(stock_to_be).await;
}
```

The Cache struct:

```
pub struct Cache {
    pub stocks: Vec<Stock>,
}
```

The stock_index_in_cache method:

```
pub fn stock_index_in_cache(&mut self, ticker: String) -> i64 {
    let stock_already_exist = self.stocks.iter().position(|stock| stock.ticker == ticker);
    match stock_already_exist {
        Some(v) => {
            return v as i64;
        }
        None => -1,
    }
}
```

And the stock struct:

```
pub struct Stock {
    pub ticker: String,
    pub statements: Statements,
    pub metrics: Metrics,
}
```

I have tried multiple recommendations on SO to avoid the multiple mut borrow issue but I either could not implement them or they did not work. What is really the issue here?

Comment: `'static: 'a` is a tautology (`'static` always outlives everything) and very unnecessary, perhaps you meant `'a: 'static` at which point you could just use `'static` instead of `'a`

Comment: Anyways without a [mre] it's hard to tell specifics. Especially what's `stock_index_in_cache`, what does `Cache` look like, what's the full error message you get.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the redundancy. I kinda thought that but was trying random things.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it is not readable here, [edit] your post instead.

Comment: Here is cache: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f66df84eee5ac994c45cdc4c596f6a32

Comment: I don't have the exact error message because I'm on my phone but it was related to burrowing a mutable inside a loop. The two things you asked for are in the playground I linked. Sorry for making it so troublesome, I'm struggling doing this on my phone.

Comment: Well untill you provide the full error and [mre] we can't really help you. Your playground still has undefined stuff in it (`use crate::…`). And your problem has to be self contained, i.e. a playground link might be nice to have, but it's no replacement for the example in the post.

Comment: My bad, I updated the post, let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Your example is still not reproducible or minimal. It gives me the error "failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Statements`" and "failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Materials`" among [very many others](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1a2df36398d4c9ea624106765c30dfe) please remove any code that is not needed to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `&'static mut`. That says “this is borrowed forever”, which is incompatible with calling a function in a loop because each call must *relinquish* the borrow, i.e. not require it to last forever. You should remove all of the `'static`s; they are unnecessary.

However, that will not be enough to make the code work, because you will still have the conflict in `symbols_to_stocks` between borrowing one `stock` from the cache and adding more to it. You can't do that, for several reasons:

- For `Vec` in particular, the `Vec` may need to reallocate and therefore move its items, invalidating prior references.
- As written, if the code *were* accepted, you could get multiple overlapping `&mut`s to the same element simply by passing the same symbol to `Stock::new` twice, which is unsound.

You will need to adopt a different strategy; the most straightforward one is to find/insert entries in the cache and get *indexes* (not references), then use that index to lookup an individual `Stock` when you want to read or modify it. Collecting a `Vec<usize>` of indexes is much more tractable than a `Vec<&mut Stock>`.

Another option is keeping `Rc<RefCell<Stock>>` in your cache, for runtime-checked ownership and borrowing; this gets you the sort of behavior you might expect from a garbage-collection-and-OOP language, but at the cost of needing to explicitly access the `RefCell` and some other complications.